# ¿Porque se tarda en responde al terminar de ejecutar un store procedure?

Tags: genexus

porque cuando ejecuta un objeto externo tipo store procedure al terminar de ejecutarse se tarda en regresar a la pantalla quien lo ejecuto y se bloquean las tablas de la base de datos

Comment: Depende de la complejidad del `SP` y dependiendo de la base este puede bloquear las tablas o no.

Comment: agrega tu SP en la pregunta para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar

Comment: No entiendo eso de que las tablas estén bloqueadas una vez ha terminado el SP. Puede que el proceso que invoca al SP sea el que bloquea porque asegure la transaccionalidad. La tardanza puede deberse al volumen de datos devuelto por el SP, que deben enviarse y quizás procesarse. Es dificil que obtengas una buena y precisa respuesta con la información que aportas.

Comment: Y qué tiene que ver genexus en esto?

Comment: Porque no desarrollamos con visual studio directo sino mediante la herramienta Genexus

el SP esta mas que probado y al ejecutarlo directo en la consola de SQL corre muy rápido y no bloquea las tablas